# Type mismatch expected: Option[Color], actual: Color

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

I have a case class like this:

```
case class ColorDetail(
    color: Option[Color],
    shades: List[Shade]
)
```

I have a method with this signature:

```
def colorFromProtoBuf(msg: ColorMessage): Color = {
 ...
}
```

When I try to do:

```
ColorDetail(
   color = colorFromtProtoBuf(...), //Type mismatch here
   shades = ...
)
```

I get a

```
Type mismatch, expected: Option[Color], actual: Color
```

How can I resolve this without changing my case class or method signature. Ideally I would like to just change the line where I'm getting an error. Is there a way I can convert it to `Option[Color]` instead of just `Color`

Answer (score 4):

```
color = Option(colorFromtProtoBuf(...))
```

`color` will be assigned to `Some(Color)` or `None` if your function returns `null`

Answer (score 3):

If `colorFromProtoBuf` is guaranteed to succeed you can simply wrap it in `Some`:

```
color = Some(colorFromProtoBuf(...))
```

If `colorFromProtoBuf` might return `null` then use `Option` which will convert `null` values to `None`:

```
color = Option(colorFromProtoBuf(...))
```

If there is a chance that `colorFromProtoBuf` might throw an error then use `Try`:

```
color = Try(colorFromProtoBuf(...)).toOption
```

Finally, if `colorFromProtoBuf` might fail and you can edit this function, change the signature to return `Option[Color]` and return `None` on failure or `Some(color)` on success.

```
def colorFromProtoBuf(msg: ColorMessage): Option[Color] = {
```

(I know this is not a one-line answer, but it might be the correct answer!)